# Professional video editor for Pi 4B

Tags: pi-4, video

I'm looking for a professional video editor for the Raspberry Pi 4B. Is there anything good that I can use? I mainly use special effects, and I split the frame a lot, so preferably with that feature. I'd also prefer it if it were a free application. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per the answer a Raspberry Pi is pretty much the exact opposite of the kind of hardware you want for this kind of work.  OTOH, apparently **blender** works: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-3d-modeling-blender-how It's not a video editor but I think on par with one, and I did not read all of that to find out *how well*.  Video formats will be an issue, I think; blender can rely on the openGL hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt the Pi 4B has the horsepower to function adequately as a professional video editor

Comment: Is at least want to try. I also have the 8gb model, so I doubt that RAM would be an issue.

Comment: A quick Google indicates it would be like video editing on a Pentium 3, almost any PC produced in the last 10 years would do a better job.

Comment: *"I at least want to try..."* -> That's great, and I am not putting you down, but try to understand that you may have to write the software yourself in that case.   There is less than zero incentive for the creators of pro level video editing software to make it work on the Pi.   Literally *less than*, because the compromises needed would loose them far more users than they stand to gain.